# Detect the face location in a picture of a person

Tags: c#, computer-vision

How can I detect and select the face in the a photo of a person in a c# windows application?
Are there any existing libraries I can use?

Comment: [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com) is a good start, but I don't think it provides C# bindings

Comment: +1 @Rup, I have used http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: You may want to look into http://www.openframeworks.cc/ it might not fit your needs but I have to try to nudge you away from Windows as a civic duty ;) If you are getting into face recognition and webcams as such you might be better in C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to implement it using AForge ( http://www.aforgenet.com/ ). It's a c# library for computer vision and artificial intelligence. And I found several threads on their forum about face recognition:
http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=591
http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1557
http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1317

Also you can use approach from this article - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/face_detection.aspx

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV .NET is what you are searching for.
Take a look here:

http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [pure C# Face Detection Library](http://htc-hd2-android.blogspot.com/2011/03/c-face-detectionface-recognition.html)

Although there is a OpenCVDotNet to wrapper OpenCV with C# language, it seems very difficult for common users to implement Simple Face Detection/Face Recognition as a simple way.Now you don't need to worry about it, because there is a developer has built a pure C# Face Detection Library.

Comment: http://www.askernest.com/archive/2008/05/03/face-detection-in-c.aspx this is the right url to the project pure C# Face Detection Library, Good, if you don't take care about some aspect like fast acquisition, others visualization elements and self-learning... But good to apply in some ASP projects maybe.

Comment: Absolutely you are right, and do you know opencvdotnet support latest opencv version? When I try to install, it often prompt error error....